# Angular how to wait for method to finish before proceeding to next line

Tags: angular, observablecollection

Inside a component, I am trying to call a method (getConfigSettings()), which in turn calls another method from a service (which returns an observable collection).

The issue is inside the main method (getConfigSettings()), the lines are not executed in sequence. That means, instead of waiting for the observable call to get finished the control moves to next line,

```
  localStorage.setItem('displayExpiryWarning', this.isEnabled ? JSON.stringify(false) : JSON.stringify(true));
```

this.isEnabled  property is not set.

code sample :

```
export class ExamComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    sub_modules: any;
    isEnabled: boolean = true;
    // .....
    // ......

    onStepA(): void {

            this.checkForCoverage();

    }



checkForCoverage(): void {

    this.getConfigSettings(); // This method never gets finished and control move to next line below        


    localStorage.setItem('displayExpiryWarning', this.isEnabled ? JSON.stringify(false) : JSON.stringify(true));

}



getConfigSettings() {
    this.sub_modules = this.ls.getProductModules().subscribe(
        (data) => {
            try {
                const dataXml = data.filter((data) => data.ModuleName == 'LoginModule')[0].XmlConfig;
                if (dataXml) {
                    const config = xmlToJson(dataXml);

                    this.isEnabled =
                        config['configuration'].appSettings.param.filter(
                            (data) => data.name == 'PropAEnabled',
                        )[0].value === 'true';            
                }                   


            } catch (e) {}
        },
        (err) => {},
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do the setting of localStorage part under `getConfigSettings()`, or else return an Observable
from `getConfigSettings()` and subscribe, wherever you want.

If you think that the data from the Observable won't change in subsequent calls of `getConfigSettings()`
then you can use `shareReplay` along with making the Observable a class property.

```
checkForCoverage(): void {
    this.getConfigSettings().subscribe(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('displayExpiryWarning', this.isEnabled ? JSON.stringify(false) : JSON.stringify(true));
    });
}



getConfigSettings() {
    return this.ls.getProductModules().pipe(tap((data) => {
        try {
            const dataXml = data.filter((data) => data.ModuleName == 'LoginModule')[0].XmlConfig;
            if (dataXml) {
                const config = xmlToJson(dataXml);

                this.isEnabled =
                    config['configuration'].appSettings.param.filter(
                        (data) => data.name == 'PropAEnabled',
                    )[0].value === 'true';            
            }                   
        } catch (e) {}
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return an observable from `getConfigSettings()` and subscribe to it in the `checkForCoverage()` function. Try the following

```js
checkForCoverage(): void {
  this.getConfigSettings().subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('displayExpiryWarning', this.isEnabled ? JSON.stringify(false) : JSON.stringify(true));
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    }
  );
}

getConfigSettings() {
  const result = new Subject<boolean>();

  this.sub_modules = this.ls.getProductModules().subscribe(
    data => {
      try {
        const dataXml = data.filter((data) => data.ModuleName == 'LoginModule')[0].XmlConfig;
        if (dataXml) {
          const config = xmlToJson(dataXml);
          this.isEnabled = config['configuration']
            .appSettings
            .param
            .filter((data) => data.name == 'PropAEnabled')[0]
            .value === 'true';
          result.next(true);      // <-- push `true` here
        }
      } catch (e) {
        result.next(false);       // <-- push `false` here
      }
    },
    err => {
      result.next(false);         // <-- push `false` here
    },
  );

  return result.asObservable();
}
```